# Value of type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'addAttributes'

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, swift4

I checked the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1414304-addattributes) and the method is there.

And when I look in the .h file I do see the function. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding and I still get this error after migrating to Swift 4.

> Value of type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'addAttributes'

On the following:

```
var options:[NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any] = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
var attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
let range = (attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: attributedString.string)
attributedString.addAttributes(baseAttributes, range: range) // ERROR!
```

Comment: That's a method of `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Comment: Ah ok this must have got lost in translation. Thank you.

Comment: If you want you can use `addAttribute` for single.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else brought here by Google, I was missing `import UIKit`